# Qt 5.1 - Can't compile example abstractitemmodel: "conflicting return type specified"

Tags: qt, qt5

I'm trying to compile the above example, however it doesn't compile (windows, Mingw 4.8). The error is:

```
In file included from ..\abstractitemmodel\main.cpp:40:0: ..\abstractitemmodel\model.h:77:27: error: conflicting return type specified for 'virtual QHash<int, QByteArray> AnimalModel::roleNames() const'
 QHash<int,QByteArray> roleNames() const;
                       ^
In file included from ..\..\..\..\include\QtCore/QAbstractListModel:1:0,
             from ..\abstractitemmodel\model.h:40,
             from ..\abstractitemmodel\main.cpp:40:
..\..\..\..\include\QtCore/qabstractitemmodel.h:234:43: error:   overriding 'virtual const QHash<int, QByteArray>& QAbstractItemModel::roleNames() const'
 virtual const QHash<int,QByteArray> & roleNames() const;
```

Obviously the prototype in the QAbstractListModel expects a reference in return and not an object. I don't know how to alter the code so it actually works though.

If I add a QHash member to the AnimalModel, initialize it in the constructor and then return a reference to it, the program crashes.

Comment: What is "the above example"? Where did you get it?

Comment: @Pavel: Qt\examples\declarative\modelviews\abstractitemmodel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of `roleNames` changed from `const QHash<int,QByteArray> &` in Qt4 to `QHash<int,QByteArray>` in Qt5.
Thus it looks like you're trying to compile a Qt5 example against Qt4.

Comment: This is very strange. I'm physically looking at the file:
`C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\mingw48_32\include\QtCore\qabstractitemmodel.h`

And it says right there:
`virtual const QHash<int,QByteArray> & roleNames() const;`

Comment: Very strange indeed. Both my local git checkout (v5.1.1 tag) and the apidocs show the signature as I said. The file from Qt 5.1.1 should look like this: https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/7fc158698850e80d679022bfcbccb7dc663e8e53:src/corelib/itemmodels/qabstractitemmodel.h

Comment: I changed the h file (removed the reference) and it works now.
There's a bug in the distribution I guess (wrong .h file included).
Thank you!

Comment: How did you install Qt?

Comment: I downloaded "Qt 5.1.1 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 4.8, OpenGL, 666 MB)" from http://qt-project.org/downloads.
I know that I was compiling against Qt5 because I have several features in my project that were not present in Qt4, and they compiled fine. The only thing that was problematic was the QAbstractItemModel which refused to work, and that's why I tried to compile an example, which also failed.